# WCF service works with localhost, but not with an IP address

Tags: wcf

I've looked through the other similar questions, but not been able to resolve my own problem.

I have a WCF service that works if I connect to it with:

```
http://localhost:35001/SchoolLightService.svc
```

but not if I use the computer's ip-address (from within the LAN):

```
http://192.168.1.4:35001/SchoolLightService.svc
```

The error message is (had to change the ip number (the above one) to "my ip" to please Stackoverflow):

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   http://"my ip":35001/SchoolLightService.svc If this is a Windows
>   (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI: http://"my ip":35001/SchoolLightService.svc
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://"my ip":35001/SchoolLightService.svc'.    There was no
>   endpoint listening at http://"my ip":35001/SchoolLightService.svc
>   that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
>   details.    Unable to connect to the remote server    No connection
>   could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   "my ip":35001HTTP GET Error    URI: http://"my ip":35001/SchoolLightService.svc    There was an error
>   downloading 'http://"my ip":35001/SchoolLightService.svc'.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server    No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it "my ip":35001

The web.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SLBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services >
      <service name="SchoolLightWCF.SchoolLightService"
              behaviorConfiguration="SLBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.4:35001" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint
          address="/SchoolLightService"
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
          contract="SchoolLightWCF.ISchoolLightService"
        />
        <endpoint
           address="mex"
           binding="mexHttpBinding"
           contract="IMetadataExchange"
        />
      </service>

    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <diagnostics>

      <messageLogging
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
            logMalformedMessages="true" logEntireMessage="true"
            maxSizeOfMessageToLog="65535000" maxMessagesToLog="500" />

    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="sharedListener"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="c:\temp\tracelog.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="sharedListener" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sharedListener" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="ApplicationLogging" switchValue="Information" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="sharedListener" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SLEntities" connectionString="...not relevant..." />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about checking the firewall?

Comment: I added an inbound rule for the port, but to no effect. I do have a router, but it shouldn't matter since I'm just working inside the local network, should it?

Comment: I tried telnet to the port. If I use localhost, it works fine. If I use the IP number (192.168.1.4), it cannot connect. Windows firewall is disabled and router has port forwarding set.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by publishing it to a real IIS server running on the computer. For some reason the built-in web server in Visual Studio didn't cut it.

Comment: Wow, I thought you do it on IIS. The built-in web server DOESN'T answer to remote requests by design.

Comment: yes, IIS will work, but is there any way to achieve this while staying in Debug in Visual studio?